# apply scroll to second list item, by keeping first list item fixed in html

Tags: html, css

i am using below code

```
 <div> 
        <div id="aboxound" >
                    <ul>
                        <li class="aHeader"  >
                            <ul>
                                <li class="Name">Names</li>
                                <li class="Name">values</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                      <li style="height:500px; overflow-y:scroll;">
     <c:forEach items="${dataModel.List}" var="entry">
                        <li class="aUser" >
                            <ul>
                             <li class="userName"><c:out value="${entry.key}" /></li>
                            <li class="userName"><c:out value="${entry.value}" /></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                </c:forEach>                    
                        </li>
                    </ul>
    </div>
                </div>
```

Here i want to apply scroll to second list, by keeping first list as fixed header. My above code is not working.it add empty scroll first and then list item without scroll. What i am doing wrong

Comment: Post your css as well.

Comment: Where is css code...

Comment: @Mr_panda   refer this i have added css   https://jsfiddle.net/bbjk/s6068e3L/

Answer (score 0):

If you write `overflow:scroll` even the not content not heavy it shows scroll, use `overflow:auto` in your code inplace `overflow-y:scroll`.